# How to change the color of a button when the input feild is filled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button, input

I've search the internet and i have not seen anybody talk about how to change the color of a button when the one input bar is filled in javascript, i dont have any code i've really tryed since there little to any sources i've seen that talk about this in in-depth.

for example lets say the color of the button is white, but when i input any form  of text, it changes colors to green. Heres a screenshot if that helps, sorry for   the horrible wording.[image]

Comment: What is an `input-bar` you mean input where you type something ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion., i ment an `<input>` feild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you want to change the color of the button when text box is filled.

You can use this method.

You can use `onKeyUp` event or `onChange` event to perform that kind of requirement.

```js
function changeButtonColor() {
  if(document.getElementById("myText").value !== "") {
     document.getElementById("myButton").style.background = "red";
  } else {
     document.getElementById("myButton").style.background = "blue";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="myText" onkeyup="changeButtonColor()">
        <br><br>
        <button id="myButton" style="background:blue">Click Me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```